Comparing performance among custom cuda kernel, cublas and cutensor
I've made the following CUDA tests to compare the performance numbers of (square) matrix multiplication, running on Ubuntu 24.04 with the GPU card Quadro T1000 Mobile of compute capability 7.5 (arch=SM_75) and the GPU driver nvidia-driver-535 .
Remark

cuda_runtime and cublas_v2 are installed via apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev, being provided by the repos archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/multiverse.
cutensor tarball is fetched and installed accordingly.

Configuration
Test              Lib                     Cores
----              ---                     ----
mat_mul_custom    cuda_runtime v12.0.1    cuda-cores
mat_mul_blas      cublas_v2 v12.0.1       cuda-cores
mat_mul_tensor    cutensor v2.0.2.4       dedicated-cuda-cores (non-tensor-cores)
n/a               cutensor                tensor-cores

Mat_mul_test.cu
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#define STRIDE 1024
#define SUB_STRIDE 32

__global__ void mat_mul_custom_d(float*, float*, float*);
__global__ void mat_mul_custom_d(float* A, float* B, float* C) {
    int by = blockIdx.y, bx = blockIdx.x, ty = threadIdx.y, tx = threadIdx.x;
    int aBegin = by * SUB_STRIDE * STRIDE + ty * STRIDE + tx,
        aEnd = aBegin + STRIDE, bBegin = SUB_STRIDE * bx + ty * STRIDE + tx,
        bStep = SUB_STRIDE * STRIDE;
    float sC = 0;
    for (int a = aBegin, b = bBegin; a < aEnd; a += SUB_STRIDE, b += bStep) {
        __shared__ float As[SUB_STRIDE][SUB_STRIDE], Bs[SUB_STRIDE][SUB_STRIDE];
        As[ty][tx] = A[a];
        Bs[ty][tx] = B[b];
        __syncthreads();
        for (int k = 0; k < SUB_STRIDE; ++k) sC += As[ty][k] * Bs[k][tx];
        __syncthreads();
    }
    C[by * SUB_STRIDE * STRIDE + SUB_STRIDE * bx + ty * STRIDE + tx] = sC;
}

void mat_mul_custom(float*, float*, float*);
void mat_mul_custom(float* A, float* B, float* C) {
    dim3 block(SUB_STRIDE, SUB_STRIDE);
    dim3 grid(STRIDE / SUB_STRIDE, STRIDE / SUB_STRIDE);
    mat_mul_custom_d<<<grid, block>>>(A, B, C);
}

#include <cublas_v2.h>
#define ALPHA 1
#define BETA 0

void mat_mul_blas(float*, float*, float*);
void mat_mul_blas(float* A, float* B, float* C) {
    const float alpha = ALPHA, beta = BETA;
    cublasHandle_t cublasH;
    cublasCreate(&cublasH);
    cublasSgemm(cublasH, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, STRIDE, STRIDE, STRIDE,
                &alpha, A, STRIDE, B, STRIDE, &beta, C, STRIDE);
}

#include <cutensor.h>
#define N_MODES 2
#define K_ALIGNMENT 128

void mat_mul_tensor(float*, float*, float*);
void mat_mul_tensor(float* A, float* B, float* C) {
    const float alpha = ALPHA, beta = BETA;
    const int modeC[] = {'i', 'j'}, modeA[] = {'i', 'k'}, modeB[] = {'k', 'j'};
    const int64_t extentC[] = {STRIDE, STRIDE}, extentA[] = {STRIDE, STRIDE},
                  extentB[] = {STRIDE, STRIDE};
    cutensorHandle_t handle;
    cutensorCreate(&handle);
    cutensorTensorDescriptor_t descA, descB, descC;
    cutensorCreateTensorDescriptor(handle, &descA, N_MODES, extentA, 0,
                                   CUTENSOR_R_32F, K_ALIGNMENT);
    cutensorCreateTensorDescriptor(handle, &descB, N_MODES, extentB, 0,
                                   CUTENSOR_R_32F, K_ALIGNMENT);
    cutensorCreateTensorDescriptor(handle, &descC, N_MODES, extentC, 0,
                                   CUTENSOR_R_32F, K_ALIGNMENT);
    cutensorOperationDescriptor_t desc;
    cutensorCreateContraction(handle, &desc, descA, modeA, CUTENSOR_OP_IDENTITY,
                              descB, modeB, CUTENSOR_OP_IDENTITY, descC, modeC,
                              CUTENSOR_OP_IDENTITY, descC, modeC,
                              CUTENSOR_COMPUTE_DESC_32F);
    cutensorPlanPreference_t planPref;
    cutensorCreatePlanPreference(handle, &planPref, CUTENSOR_ALGO_DEFAULT,
                                 CUTENSOR_JIT_MODE_NONE);
    cutensorPlan_t plan;
    cutensorCreatePlan(handle, &plan, desc, planPref, 0);
    cutensorContract(handle, plan, (void*)&alpha, A, B, (void*)&beta, C, C, 0,
                     0, 0);
}

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define RAND_UPPER 2

void mat_mul(void (*mat_mul_impl)(float*, float*, float*), bool);
void mat_mul(void (*mat_mul_impl)(float*, float*, float*), bool column_major) {
    float *A, *B, *C;
    cudaMallocManaged(&A, sizeof(float) * STRIDE * STRIDE);
    cudaMallocManaged(&B, sizeof(float) * STRIDE * STRIDE);
    cudaMallocManaged(&C, sizeof(float) * STRIDE * STRIDE);
    for (int i = 0; i < STRIDE; i++)
        for (int k = 0; k < STRIDE; k++)
            A[i * STRIDE + k] = rand() % RAND_UPPER;
    for (int j = 0; j < STRIDE; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < STRIDE; k++)
            B[k * STRIDE + j] = rand() % RAND_UPPER;
    if (column_major)
        mat_mul_impl(B, A, C);
    else
        mat_mul_impl(A, B, C);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    for (int i = 0; i < STRIDE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < STRIDE; j++) {
            float res = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < STRIDE; k++)
                res += A[i * STRIDE + k] * B[k * STRIDE + j];
            assert(res == C[i * STRIDE + j]);
        }
    cudaFree(A);
    cudaFree(B);
    cudaFree(C);
}

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "custom")) {
            printf("Test: mat_mul_custom\n");
            mat_mul(mat_mul_custom, false);
            return 0;
        }
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "blas")) {
            printf("Test: mat_mul_blas\n");
            mat_mul(mat_mul_blas, true);
            return 0;
        }
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "tensor")) {
            printf("Test: mat_mul_tensor\n");
            mat_mul(mat_mul_tensor, true);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Usage: nvprof ./Mat_mul_test [custom|blas|tensor]\n");
}

Tests
$ nvcc ./Mat_mul_test.cu \
       -lcublas \ 
       -L${CUTENSOR_ROOT}/lib/12 \
       -lcutensor \
       -I${CUTENSOR_ROOT}/include \
       -o ./Mat_mul_test

$ nvprof ./Mat_mul_test custom

     Avg    Name
     ---    ----
15.352ms    mat_mul_custom_d

   Count    Total Time    Name
   -----    ----------    ----
      35    4.641ms       Gpu page fault groups

$ nvprof ./Mat_mul_test blas

 4.628ms    volta_sgemm_128x64_nn

      28    3.627ms       Gpu page fault groups

$ nvprof ./Mat_mul_test tensor

 4.879ms    volta_sgemm_128x64_nn

      31    4.441ms       Gpu page fault groups

The GPU under test does not have tensor cores in hardware, but has the hardware to process tensor instructions. The tests between mat_mul_blas and mat_mul_tensor exhibit almost the same performance numbers. Are they as expected? What does the kernel volta_sgemm_128x64_nn execute exactly? The test mat_mul_blas is much faster than mat_mul_custom. Is it just because the kernel volta_sgemm_128x64_nn is highly optimized, or mostly because they execute on different types of CUDA cores?
Reference

Nvidia custom cuda kernel sample
Nvidia cublas sample
Nvidia cutensor sample
Why cublas


As you wrote yourself there is no float32 tensor cores, so what other types of CUDA cores should there be? You can use tools like the Source page of Nsight Compute or cuobjdump to look at the actual SASS instructions used.

As your kernel contains a fair amount of __syncthreads(), you could try running smaller (32x16) blocks to allow 2 blocks per SM and therefore avoid under-utilization when most warps of a block wait on the barrier. Turing (sm_75) allows max 32 warps per SM.

Thanks, @paleonix! Nvidia GPUs are fast evolving and vast info scatters around.  It's merely my own speculation and I'm eagerly looking for evidence. Later, I'll look into Nsight tooling as suggested.

While it might not a problem for this comparison, I would generally prefetch the data to the device after the initialization of the unified memory on the host to avoid measuring the time of the page faults/transfer (not sure how nvprof handles this).

Your Quadro T1000 Mobile uses the same hardware/die (TU117) as a GTX 1650 so the post you linked about tensor instructions certainly applies. I'm just not sure if that kernel will use tensor instructions in the first place as there are no fp32 tensor cores, only tf32.

@paleonix, I updated the numbers of page faults. They are quite close.

Yeah the faults happen independent of the method, that is why I wrote that they might not matter in the comparison. But the relative performance might differ when prefetching. Or maybe nvprof just runs the kernel multiple times and takes the measurement at a point where the pages are already on the GPU.

@paleonix, I tried on even smaller (16x16) blocks and the performance numbers became slightly worse. Later, I'll try on 32x16.

It is a tradeoff between latency hiding and data-reuse, so it is hard to predict where the sweet spot is.

@paleonix, to be clear about the tradeoff: the more warps per block, the better latency hiding potentially, but the worse efficient concurrency actually due to sync barrier. OTH the more shared memory, the better data locality. Is that what you meant?

The more blocks per SM, the better is the latency hiding in the presence of block synchronization. The bigger the block (and with it the shared memory), the better the data reuse.


Are they as expected?

Yes, its expected that cublas will do matrix multiplication operations faster than the kernel code you have shown.  It's also evident that the cutensor designers are using roughly the same approach as cublas - in fact its evident they are calling cublas in a similar fashion to your cublas call. (the durations are basically the same, and the kernel name is the same)

What does the kernel volta_sgemm_128x64_nn execute exactly?

It's a highly-optimized gemm kernel (matrix-matrix multiply) for FP32 data (which is why you see sgemm), written by the cublas designers, as part of the closed source cublas library.  Therefore I cannot provide a detailed description.  However writing a highly optimized gemm kernel is a non-trivial undertaking.  This writeup may give you some idea of the complexity involved, compared to your kernel code, which we now might refer to as a "naive" shared-memory matrix multiply code.

Is it just because the kernel volta_sgemm_128x64_nn is highly optimized, or mostly because they execute on different types of CUDA cores?

It is because it is highly optimized.  They are not using different cores (functional units in the SM).  You can get some evidence/proof of this by using the CUDA binary utilities.  If you dump the SASS code in each case, you will find both your kernel and the cublas sgemm kernel are using FFMA SASS instructions to perform the matrix-multiply arithmetic.
As has already been mentioned, there are currently no CUDA GPUs that provide tensorcore calculation paths for FP32 input data, so we can completely dispense with that notion at this time; that is not what is happening here, and the fact that both your cublas call and your cutensor call are invoking a cublas non-tensorcore sgemm routine is further evidence of that.

Thanks, @Robert Crovella! SM_7x consists of 64(FP32) and 32(FP64) etc. Why does my T1000 only report total 64 cores per SM? Were the rest cores disabled on the GPU die for shipment?

@sof Read the footnote: "2 FP64 cores for double-precision arithmetic operations for devices of compute capabilities 7.5". Only few big server accelerators have good FP64 compute, in this case the V100.

@paleonix, well, it actually states: 64(FP32), 32(FP64 for servers), 64(INT64), 8(tensor), 16(SFU) and 4(WS).

@paleonix. I read this, where I have the answer partially. (Quote: The term "core" in CUDA is generally used to refer to a SP unit. And just because a SM contains, for example 128 CUDA cores (i.e. SP units), does not mean that it also contains 128 DP units, or 128 LD/ST units, or a particular number of any other functional unit type. The number of functional units in a SM can and do vary by functional unit type.)

@sof Yeah, "CUDA cores" is a marketing term that only describes the number of FP32 units. I didn't realize that that was the source of confusion for you. What is still unclear?

@paleonix, thanks for your constant helps. There're many Nvidia/CUDA/marketing terms. Especially, the "core" has caused me lots of confusion. Because the GPU specs/manual (if I could find) just provides me with the info lack of details on cuda cores, and we're unable to query the device for  e.g. the core types and the quantities, sometimes, I can hardly reason some of the performance numbers w/o these concretes in hardware. OTH, just out of curiosity I'd like to know if the GPU dies are elastically made, simply being enabled/disabled some functional units for market differentiation.

@sof Generally I would think that full SMs are fused off rather than parts of an SM.
